# What kind of type should r-value reference parameter be in doxygen? [in] or [in, out]?

Tags: c++, doxygen

```
/**
 * @param[?] u
 */
T func(U&& u);
```

The parameter `u` may be modified by `func`, while the modified status should be ignored seeing it's an r-value reference.

I haven't found any information about that, including the Doxygen Manual.

Comment: I always use these to denote information flow, not mutability. There's an argument to be made for the latter. Since you're not getting usable information in the `[out]` direction (`u` should be left in an undefined-but-valid state), then it's purely `[in]`. But with a note that the variable is moved from and therefore left in an undefined state. (Unless `U`'s move semantics do something OTHER than leave it in an other-than-undefined-but-valid state.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not think in terms of "it's a reference, so that means X". You should think in terms of what `u` means to the function and what the function is doing with it. Merely moving from `u` is not enough to declare it an `[inout]` parameter. `[inout]` or `[out]` should be used when the function is deliberately setting a value to it that the user is expected to use. If you move from a rvalue-reference parameter, the user's parameter *has no value* anymore. That's kind of the antithesis of an "output".

Indeed, an rvalue reference parameter *cannot* be bound to an lvalue argument (directly). This means that a user can't just call `func(some_variable)`; they have to explicitly move into it: `func(std::move(some_variable));`. That spelling doesn't feel like an output value; it's transferring something *into* the function. It would be a weird interface indeed if the user were expecting `some_variable` to have a new value, especially since `func(some_type());` would effectively discard the "output" value.